# How do I hide the Windows system tray in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a working Windows app that appears as an icon in the Windows system tray.  When I click on my icon in the system tray it opens my application window, but the expanded system tray doesn't disappear.  How do I tell the expanded system tray to hide itself once I've launched my application?

Answer (score 5):

You don't. The notification area (often called "system tray") manages that stuff by itself, and applications shouldn't mess with it (that's why there are no APIs to affect substantially its behavior); [read e.g. here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/22/10270776.aspx).